# Processor affinity on mac.

Tags: cpu, macos

In Linux machines, there is a command called `taskset`, which can be used to do the processor affinity.

In mac(from mavericks) are there any commands to the same job like `taskset`?

Else how one can achieve processor affinity on mac?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Apple provides a [Thread Affinity API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Performance/RN-AffinityAPI/), but nothing like taskset.

> OS X does not export interfaces that identify processors or control thread placement—explicit thread to processor binding is not supported. Instead, the kernel manages all thread placement.  Applications expect that the scheduler will, under most circumstances, run its threads using a good processor placement with respect to cache affinity.

Comment: Thanks. Any examples of how to use them?