# How do I get information specific to CPU core via command

Tags: macos, command-line, cpu

Suppose we have one CPU with 2 cores. I seek dynamic scheduling information such as Processes, IO time, IDLE Time, System Time as allocated time specific cores as opposed to aggregated or averaged to a multi core CPU.

Below I have prepared a command but it is giving above information on CPU level and not on core level.

```
sh-3.2# top -l 15 | grep -i "Processes" | tail -2

Processes: 387 total, 2 running, 385 sleeping, 1677 threads

Processes: 386 total, 2 running, 384 sleeping, 1672 threads
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/166871/115093) you can't.  macOS *"does not export interfaces that identify processors or control thread placement"*

Comment: I'd be interested to know what your end goal is for this information.

Comment: @lx07 That is a misunderstanding. Chandrakant wants to get information about CPU usage per core. The answer you've linked says that you cannot control which CPU core a thread is run on (this is normally known as thread affinity). It's two different things.

Comment: @jksoegaard you could be right - the question was way too soft if we’re going to talk about thread affinity as opposed to averaged workload metrics. I tried to sharpen the question. Let’s see what OP actually requests

Comment: Chandrakamt - it would help if you specify one actual Mac CPU you care about in your example for top and a specific macOS version.

Comment: @bmike I disagree. This question is definitely not about thread affinity - so that answer won’t apply here at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the program `htop` from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), which will give you this information.

When you have Homebrew installed, run the following command to install:

```
brew install htop
```

Afterwards you can run the program like this:

```
htop
```

If you go into the `Setup` menu by typing `S` and select `Display Options`, you can enable detailed CPU information. The CPU usage bar then displays information about the CPU usage, system (i.e. kernel) time, io time, etc.

Comment: thanks. but above command will give core specific utilization only and not idel time, IO time, System time.  is there any mac  api expose  to get all core specific information.

Comment: That information is available in the program... I have detailed how to enable the display of it in the setup menu...

Comment: @nohillside - you put an edit to type `S` for setup menu.  For me (version 2.2.0 compiled today from [source](http://hisham.hm/htop/index.php?page=downloads) not via homebew) setup is `F2` while `s` invokes strace.

Comment: @lx07 lower-case triggers strace, upper-case setup :-) See https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/htop.1.in, line 108