# I need information specific to CPU core. Is there any api exposed for mac

Tags: macos, mac

Suppose we have one CPU with 2 core , then I need information about no.of.Processes , IO time,IDLE Time, System Time, Name of core for specific core Level and not to CPU Level etc.
So I would you like to know is there any api expose for mac.

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376703/how-do-i-get-information-specific-to-cpu-core-via-command
I'd still be interested to know why you want this information: what do you plan to use it for? If you're hoping to manage the core usage, then that's impossible or unnecessary.

Comment: There is no need to repost a question, just add additional information to your original question if required/helpful.